# Entity FW web service updates unexposed fields to null

Tags: .net, web-services, entity-framework, entity

I have a web service called from JavaScript. JS passes an object which is later cast to an Entity object in the server. The problem is there are fields in the entity that are not present in passed JSON. These non-present fields update to null value in the DB.

For example you have a Customer table with a Password field. Password is not exposed and not retrieved from web service object. But when I update the Customer row Password is set to null. Is there a way to tell the EF not to change the Password field?

I could have copied the fields manually but I'm trying to make a web page that automatically save the fields I want it to. Here's bit of code used. T is generic for Entity class.

```
    private ObjectContext _context;
    private IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

    protected abstract ObjectContext getObjectContext();

    private ObjectContext prepareObjectContext()
    {
        _context = getObjectContext();
        _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        return _context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public override ActionResult Save(SavedData data)
    {
        using (ObjectContext oc = prepareObjectContext())
        {

            if (data.inserted != null && data.inserted.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (T row in data.inserted)
                {
                    _objectSet.AddObject(row);
                    _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(row, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
                }
            }

            if (data.updated != null && data.updated.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (T row in data.updated)
                {
                    _objectSet.Attach(row);
                    _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(row, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                }
            }

            if (data.deleted != null && data.deleted.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (T row in data.deleted)
                {
                    _objectSet.Attach(row);
                    _objectSet.DeleteObject(row);
                    _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(row, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
                }
            }

            oc.SaveChanges();

            //CMManagement.Models.CMEntities
            ViewBag.columns = Columns;
            return Json(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach an entity and set its state to modified all fields will be updated. The reason is that EF doesn't know what fields have really changed. If your page posts only subset of fields you must tell EF explicitly which fields you want to update:

```
if (data.updated != null && data.updated.Count > 0) {
    foreach (T row in data.updated) {
        _objectSet.Attach(row);
        var entry = _context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(row);
        foreach (string property in PropertiesToBeUpdated) {
            entry.SetModifiedProperty(property);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also need to set some of fields as unmodified while inserting into the table. Unfortunately there is no SetUnmodified method. Is there any possible workaround?

Comment: Reverting property modification is possible only in .NET 4.5.